# VBA remove " from cell content in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to vba coding (and coding in general) but I have started doing a small macro that transfers values of a csv file into an excel file.

My next step is to remove the quotation marks in each cell. I have tried these lines of codes in my sub:

```
Dim Table As Range
Dim Cell As Variant

Set Table = Range("A1:currentregion")

For Each Cell In Table        
    cell.value2 = Replace(cell.value2,""","")   *I get a syntax error here*        
Next Cell
```

I know this is very basic but I can't find a solution on the net or using the macro recorder. If anybody could tell me what I am doing wrong and also what code I could use to change the value in a cell that contains a string of numbers into a numeric value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to loop through each cell. The `Range("A1").CurrentRegion` may be operated on as a whole.

```
With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    .Replace What:="""", Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlPart
End With
```

Note that to look for a single quote (e.g. ") you need 4 quotes in a row. An alternative is `Chr(34)` as a quote symbol is the 34th ASCII character.

**Addendum:**

With regard to the second portion of your question, changing text that looks like a number to actual numbers is best done with a quick Text to Columns ► Fixed Width command. Each column would have to be run through individually but this can be accomplished within the `.CurrentRegion`.

```
Dim c As Long
With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    .Replace What:="""", Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlPart
    For c = 1 To .Columns.Count
        .Columns(c).NumberFormat = "General"
        .Columns(c).TextToColumns Destination:=.Columns(c), _
            DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, 1)
    Next c
End With
```

There is the question of what number format the columns were in to begin with. If they were *Text* (e.g. '.NumberFormat = "@"` then removing the quotes is not going to convert them to true numbers. I've added a reversion to the *General* number format to accommodate this. If you have existing number formats that you wish to keep, there are more precise ways of reverting the number formats of *some* of the cells.

Comment: @MikeD - please see addendum to my post that addresses the second part of your question.

Comment: @user3819867 Thank you very much! Because of your input, I get to understand a little bit more and my first macro now works as desired!! I love learning vba, it even starts becoming an addiction :P

Answer (score 1):

Cell.Value2 = Replace(Cell.Value2, Chr(34), "")
There always is a workaround, this one is referencing via character code.

Answer (score -1):

You should dim Cell as Range. Also it's not a very good idea to name a variable using a VBA syntax element. Use MyTable and MyCell instead.

And to set the range better use

Set MyTable = [A1]

For Each MyCell In MyTable.CurrentRegion

...

Comment: `Cell` is not a reserved word although `Cells` is. There's no reason not to use it, and it's a very common practice.